# Sort a multi dimensional array in php using keys

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a multi dimensional array like:

```
[
   {
      "C":[
         {
            "status":"0",
            "num":"3223"
         },
         {
            "status":"1",
            "num":"45186"
         },
         {
            "status":"2",
            "num":"8310"
         },
         {
            "status":"3",
            "num":"82"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "F":[
         {
            "status":"0",
            "num":"1506"
         },
         {
            "status":"1",
            "num":"31253"
         },
         {
            "status":"2",
            "num":"1660"
         },
         {
            "status":"5",
            "num":"1017"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "A":[
         {
            "status":"0",
            "num":"1506"
         },
         {
            "status":"1",
            "num":"31253"
         },
         {
            "status":"2",
            "num":"1660"
         },
         {
            "status":"5",
            "num":"1017"
         }
      ]
   },
]
```

I want to sort this based on the keys (`C`, `F`, `A`) etc. I thought about writing my own selection sort kind of sorting method using `foreach`s, but I am sure it's not a very good way to do. I can also use `ksort()`, `usort()`, but not sure how.

I don't need anyone to write the whole code for me please, I will appreciate guidance about what is the best way to go about sorting an array like this.

The above string is actually an `json_encode()` dump of the array.

Here is the `var_dump()`:

```
array(6) { [0] => array(1) { 'C' => array(8) { [0] => array(2) { ... } [1] => array(2) { ... } [2] => array(2) { ... } [3] => array(2) { ... } [4] => array(2) { ... } [5] => array(2) { ... } [6] => array(2) { ... } [7] => array(2) { ... } } } [1] => array(1) { 'F' => array(8) { [0] => array(2) { ... } [1] => array(2) { ... } [2] => array(2) { ... } [3] => array(2) { ... } [4] => array(2) { ... } [5] => array(2) { ... } [6] => array(2) { ... } [7] => array(2) { ... } } } [2] => array(1) { 'A' => array(8) { [0] => array(2) { ... } [1] => array(2) { ... } [2] => array(2) { ... } [3] => array(2) { ... } [4] => array(2) { ... } [5] => array(2) { ... } [6] => array(2) { ... } [7] => array(2) { ... } } } [3] => array(1) { 'D' => array(8) { [0] => array(2) { ... } [1] => array(2) { ... } [2] => array(2) { ... } [3] => array(2) { ... } [4] => array(2) { ... } [5] => array(2) { ... } [6] => array(2) { ... } [7] => array(2) { ... } } } [4] => array(1) { 'E' => array(8) { [0] => array(2) { ... } [1] => array(2) { ... } [2] => array(2) { ... } [3] => array(2) { ... } [4] => array(2) { ... } [5] => array(2) { ... } [6] => array(2) { ... } [7] => array(2) { ... } } } [5] => array(1) { 'B' => array(8) { [0] => array(2) { ... } [1] => array(2) { ... } [2] => array(2) { ... } [3] => array(2) { ... } [4] => array(2) { ... } [5] => array(2) { ... } [6] => array(2) { ... } [7] => array(2) { ... } } }}
```

Above's pretty print

```
array(6) {
  [0] =>
  array(1) {
    'C' =>
    array(8) {
      [0] =>
      array(2) {
        ...
      }
      [1] =>
      array(2) {
        ...
      }
      [2] =>
      array(2) {
        ...
      }
      [3] =>
      array(2) {
        ...
      }
      [4] =>
      array(2) {
        ...
      }
      [5] =>
      array(2) {
        ...
      }
      [6] =>
      array(2) {
        ...
      }
      [7] =>
      array(2) {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
  [1] =>
  array(1) {
    'F' =>
    array(8) {
      [0] =>
      array(2) {
        ...
      }
      [1] =>
      array(2) {
        ...
      }
      [2] =>
      array(2) {
        ...
      }
      [3] =>
      array(2) {
        ...
      }
      [4] =>
      array(2) {
        ...
      }
      [5] =>
      array(2) {
        ...
      }
      [6] =>
      array(2) {
        ...
      }
      [7] =>
      array(2) {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
  [2] =>
  array(1) {
    'A' =>
    array(8) {
      [0] =>
      array(2) {
        ...
      }
      [1] =>
      array(2) {
        ...
      }
      [2] =>
      array(2) {
        ...
      }
      [3] =>
      array(2) {
        ...
      }
      [4] =>
      array(2) {
        ...
      }
      [5] =>
      array(2) {
        ...
      }
      [6] =>
      array(2) {
        ...
      }
      [7] =>
      array(2) {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
  [3] =>
  array(1) {
    'D' =>
    array(8) {
      [0] =>
      array(2) {
        ...
      }
      [1] =>
      array(2) {
        ...
      }
      [2] =>
      array(2) {
        ...
      }
      [3] =>
      array(2) {
        ...
      }
      [4] =>
      array(2) {
        ...
      }
      [5] =>
      array(2) {
        ...
      }
      [6] =>
      array(2) {
        ...
      }
      [7] =>
      array(2) {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
  [4] =>
  array(1) {
    'E' =>
    array(8) {
      [0] =>
      array(2) {
        ...
      }
      [1] =>
      array(2) {
        ...
      }
      [2] =>
      array(2) {
        ...
      }
      [3] =>
      array(2) {
        ...
      }
      [4] =>
      array(2) {
        ...
      }
      [5] =>
      array(2) {
        ...
      }
      [6] =>
      array(2) {
        ...
      }
      [7] =>
      array(2) {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
  [5] =>
  array(1) {
    'B' =>
    array(8) {
      [0] =>
      array(2) {
        ...
      }
      [1] =>
      array(2) {
        ...
      }
      [2] =>
      array(2) {
        ...
      }
      [3] =>
      array(2) {
        ...
      }
      [4] =>
      array(2) {
        ...
      }
      [5] =>
      array(2) {
        ...
      }
      [6] =>
      array(2) {
        ...
      }
      [7] =>
      array(2) {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure, I tried, it cannot get inside the third level or so.

Comment: I don't even know if you need to use multisort. Wouldn't you just ksort the top-level array? It should sort the top level keys by alpha. The result would be A, C, F in that case. Unless the original question wasn't defined enough, that should sort the array properly.

OP, is the desire to sort the top-level, and then sort by status?

Comment: @jkinz Do you mean ksort($whateverArray)? It doesn't work for me for some reason. Though it really should.

Comment: Can you var_dump the actual array? If the keys are really A, C, F it should work. The very first example on the ksort doc page is alpha sort, so I'm wondering if there is something else going on here.

Comment: @jkinz I pasted the var dump, I do see something goofy there.

Comment: @JohnSmith Thanks, that explains why the ksort isn't working. I'll get back in a little bit with a solution. Looks like a multisort will be in order here. Just to clarify, you only need the alpha sort, correct?

Comment: @jkinz Yes, just alphabetical sorting of the keys. I dont know what is going on. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi Joel, I have also added above's pretty print if that would be helpful.

Comment: @jkinz did you have a chance to look at it and suggest me something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I accomplished this. There is probably a better way,  but we need to create a new array in memory with the alpha-characters as the actual keys (basically we are removing the parent arrays we don't need). Then we use ksort to actually sort the array.

```
<?php 
$test = array(
    array("a" => array("status" =>1, "blah" => 2)),
    array("f" => array("status" =>1, "blah" => 2)),
    array("c" => array("status" =>1, "blah" => 2)),
    array("b" => array("status" =>1, "blah" => 2)),
    array("z" => array("status" =>1, "blah" => 2))
);
foreach($test as $key=>$val){
    foreach($val as $key2=>$val2){
        $newTest[$key2] = $val2;
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($test);
ksort($newTest);
var_dump($newTest);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: It probably isn't the most efficient, so if you have a lot of objects you may want to think about ways to optimize it, but if you're working with a small dataset it shouldn't be too impactful to performance. Glad it worked for you!